# How to make options (public or private) on Post? in reactjs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm creating Social Network app using MERN. I have made it so far that users can create posts and have followers and followings. My task is to make an option on the post so it can be public or private. I don't know how to do that. Has anybody idea or example of code how to do it? Thanks!

This is my post model:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      caption: String,
    
      image: {
        public_id: String,
        url: String,
      },
    
      owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
    
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
      likes: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
        },
      ],
    
      comments: [
        {
          user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
          },
          comment: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    visibility: {
  type: String,
  enum : ["public", "private"],
  default: "public"
},

    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

This is my user model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a name"],
  },

  avatar: {
    public_id: String,
    url: String,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter an email"],
    unique: [true, "Email already exists"],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
    minlength: [6, "Password must be at least 6 characters"],
    select: false,
  },

  posts: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post",
    },
  ],
  followers: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],

  following: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],

  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpire: Date,
});

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  }

  next();
});

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

userSchema.methods.generateToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
};

userSchema.methods.getResetPasswordToken = function () {
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");

  this.resetPasswordToken = crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(resetToken)
    .digest("hex");
  this.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;

  return resetToken;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

and here is the logic how of creating post:

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.image, {
      folder: "posts",
    });
    const newPostData = {
      caption: req.body.caption,
      image: {
        public_id: myCloud.public_id,
        url: myCloud.secure_url,
      },
      owner: req.user._id,
    };

    const post = await Post.create(newPostData);

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    user.posts.unshift(post._id);

    await user.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Post created",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `post`'s model, you can add a "visibility" field with private & public as possible values (one of them default, obviously). Then every time you are querying for that post or list of posts, use that visibility column to decide if  the user should be served that post or a 403 response page.

Check this for [enum](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators) validation.

Comment: Added those lines in post model....now? please help me. I don't know how to implement those lines properly.